# Nuget references in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I had the solution in `VisualStudio 2012` with some nugets packages installed with chosen version by me. After migrating to `VisualStudio 2013` I find out that packages are referenced from hard drive instead of nuget.

In nuget I installed `WindowsAzure.Storage`, version `3.1.0.1`.
After migration there is `WindowsAzure.Storage` referenced from hard drive, version `3.0.3.0`.

In project .csproj file I have:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=3.1.0.1, ...>
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\WindowsAzure.Storage.3.1.0.1\lib\net40\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

I can see that nuget didn't set `SpecificVersion` to `true`, so `VisualStudio` is using version it found on hard drive instead of downloading one from `nuget`.

Is there any way to change it without some nasty hacks so it will always download dlls from  `nuget` if package was installed by `nuget`.

Answer (score 0):

How about restoring all your packag:
[NuGet Package Restore](https://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore)

Comment: It works if packaged is not found yet. In this particular situation VS founds package in hard drive, so nuget is not restoring it as it is referenced "correctly".

Comment: Then in that case I would do a reinstall like the following: Update-Package –reinstall <packageName>